# Elasticsearch - return only the source data part

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I want to get only the `json` data from `elasticsearch` through `node js`.
I used

```
client.search({
   index: 'dashboard',
   type: 'test',
   filterPath: 'hits.hits._source',
   body: {
      query: { match_all: {} } 
   }
})
```

It will show the result as:

```
{"_source":{"datatime":"2017-08-21 16:03:00","time_of_day":11},{"_source":{"datatime":"2017-08-21 16:03:00","time_of_day":222}]
```

May I know how to select only the data part in the source through node js, without "_source"? Only `{"datatime":"2017-08-21 16:03:00","time_of_day":11},{"datatime":"2017-08-21 16:03:00","time_of_day":222}`

Comment: You cannot do that, but it is very easy to do it in your JS client code.

Comment: @Val You are right. found the way to do it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved.
can use `hits.hits._source.theDataName`, such as `hits.hits._source.datatime` , it will show `"datatime":"2017-08-21 16:03:00"`